# "fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory" on Linux/Ubuntu using g++ compiler

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile using g++ and I get the error "fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory". I'm doing #include <curses.h> and I have installed all the packages on the mingw installer such as libncurses-dev and libncurses-dll, also did in the terminal "$ sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev" and I even did "sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev". When I include <curses.h> I get no underlines and it locates functions such as initscr().. How am I still getting this and how do I fix, thank you.
Edit: I was seeing intellisense underlines/include errors when I did #include <ncurses.h>, but when I did <curses.h> they were gone.

Comment: I think you want to provide some more details about the mingw installer (where are you using it?) and the underlines (where exactly are you seeing or not seeing them?).

Comment: Basically im pretty sure the ncurses is installed but when i try to compile it with g++ file.cpp -lncurses, I get fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory

Comment: What's the include paths?  `\`g++ -print-prog-name=cc1plus\` -v` would give you the default include paths.  If curses.h is not installed amongst those, you'd need to explicitly specify -I.  Normally, I'd imagine it'd be installed under /usr/include...

Comment: `libncurses5-dev` installs both `/usr/include/curses.h` and `/usr/include/ncurses.h` (as a symbolic link to the former file). If you don't have these files, reinstall the package and make sure the installation command succeeds. If you do have these files, reinstall `g++` and make sure that the command `g++` refers to `/usr/bin/g++`. If nothing helps, reinstall Ubuntu.